# In Angular 13, "optimization": true in angular.json - Error -> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null

Tags: angular

I migrated the angular application from Angular 11 to Angular 13. In angular.json file i have kept **"optimization": true**.

Then i am building the application using npm run build:prod. Then i am putting the content of the dist folder into the server. Then the application is breaking due to some components are not packaged properly.

May anyone help on this if any idea on this?

I tried by making **"optimization": false**. It is working fine.

Comment: what is the error you are getting when optimization is true? please attach the errors on the question!

Comment: @NarenMurali when i am making optimization is true then i am getting the below error - **Error -> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'ɵcmp')**

Some components are going through the component registry and not registered. The module under which that particular component is present that module is getting loaded. But that component is not created or loaded

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:

```
ng build --prod --named-chunks --verbose --build-optimizer=false --source-map
```

Then check what error it shows, fix it and it should work after.

Comment: First i entered the below command 

$ ng build --prod --named-chunks --verbose --build-optimizer=false --source-map
Option "--prod" is deprecated: Use "--configuration production" instead.
An unhandled exception occurred: Configuration 'production' is not set in the workspace.

Comment: Then after error i ran the below and another error is coming

$ ng build --configuration production --named-chunks --verbose --build-optimizer=false --source-map
An unhandled exception occurred: Configuration 'production' is not set in the workspace.